# Dealing with very small and unbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, small-sample, train

I am working on some TV series data, so the number of records is very limited. I have 58 instances, one for each existing episode, which I have randomly split in 45 and 13. The main goal is to make a classification over  five classes.

In order to make everything even worse, the data was unbalanced:

```
Feature    Dim
---------+-----
Class 1  | 24
Class 2  | 15
Class 3  |  7
Class 4  |  7
Class 5  |  5
```

This is why I applied SMOTE to the training data, but this keeps me with the problem of having a very small testing dataset. In fact, this is how the test data is distributed:

```
Feature    Dim
---------+-----
Class 1  |  5
Class 2  |  3
Class 3  |  2
Class 4  |  2
Class 5  |  1
```

How can I measure performance on such little data? I can't tell how many "Class 5" elements it is able to recognize, because there is just one element.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: This will require a large amount of background reading as you have violated a whole variety of statistical principles.  Sorry to not have good news.  Check out [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms) and fharrell.com/post/classification and note that the minimum sample size for data splitting to work well as a validation method is on the order of n=20,000.  You're too subject to "the luck of the split" and are using methods that are harmed by imbalance.  Good methods are not hurt by imbalance except for having a lower effective sample size that makes standard errors larger.

Comment: Do you have data about one single TV series? In other words, what is the population of TV series that you are studying?

Comment: @dipetkov Thank you for your interest. I have the data about each existing episode of a tv series, 58 episodes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you are trying to solve. Is this series going to have more seasons? If the series is concluded, then why are you building a classification model?

Comment: It's not really anything that will be used, it is to demonstrate that it could be possible to forecast the popularity of an episode by using some features extracted from scripts/video

Comment: Forecasting implies taking the time dimension and order of episode into account. It's not immediately obvious how you'll make a forecasting argument from a classification model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Train/test split sounds like a bad idea indeed. I'd try [jackknife resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_resampling)/LeaveOneOut cross-validation for this case.